How can I convert a normal map to a "tangent map" of sorts? for use in an anisotropic shader
(Blend file is at the bottom of the post)
The tangent node doesn't have any input for a normal map texture so it's always just the raw per-vertex values. If you wanted to make an anisotropic shader using the vertex tangent then the none of the normal map details would carry over.
I have this set-up here which gives me exactly what I'm looking for, however it's effectively just recreating the "normal map" node but with the tangent and normal vectors swapped.

So my question is, is there a way to get this same result using a normal map node? If I try taking the cross-product of the normal map node's result and the UV tangents (as mentioned in this post How would I get the full TBN matrix from just a normal map?), it gives me a working "bitangent" map, but if I try taking the cross-product of the normal map node and the bitangent, it gives me this weird low-strength tangent map that I can't seem to fix.


